# Return a promise inside the forEach

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, ionic3

Could you tell me how can I return a `promise` on `deleteBudgets()` method below? Because I need to use `await` inside the `updateBudgets()` method.

*deleteBudgets*

```
  deleteBudgets(data: Budget[], projectId: string): Promise<void> {
    forEach(data, (d: Budget) => {
      this.fireStore.doc(`projects/${projectId}/budgets/${d.id}`).delete();//here it returns Promise<void>
    });
  }
```

*updateBudgets*

```
 updateBudgets(data: Budget[], projectId: string): Budget[] {
    await this.deleteBudgets();//here  

    let budgets: Budget[] = [];
    forEach(data, (d) => {
      const budgetId: string = this.fireStore.createId();
      d.id = budgetId;
      budgets.push(d);
      this.fireStore.doc<Budget>(`projects/${projectId}/budgets/${budgetId}`).set({
        id: budgetId,
        amount: d.amount,
        contingency: d.contingency,
        budgetGroup: d.budgetGroup,
        creationTime: moment().format()
      })
    })
    return budgets;
  }
```

Comment: Use `data.map()` and `Promis.all` on result in `deleteBudgets`

Comment: Why do you need use await? You can use call backs and implement your remaining code block in your call back function.

Comment: It would be great if you can put it in a solution. Then I can test it. Now it is not clear to me. @ponury-kostek

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an array of promises:

```
deleteBudgets(data: Budget[], projectId: string): Promise<void> {
  data.map((d: Budget) => this.fireStore.doc(`projects/${projectId}/budgets/${d.id}`).delete());
}
```

Then use promise.all to wait for all the promises to be resolved:

```
deleteBudgets(data: Budget[], projectId: string): Promise<void[]> {
  return Promise.all(data.map((d: Budget) => this.fireStore.doc(`projects/${projectId}/budgets/${d.id}`).delete()));
}
```

Docs for the [promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks a lot :)